# iPad "draggable window"

Tags: ipad, windowing

When you load a view on the iPad it tends to fill the whole screen.

Is there a way to create a "draggable windowed view" on the iPad?

Answer (score 3):

You could definitely do that by implementing the various [`UIResponder` methods for touching](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW13), but I caution you against this approach, as movable windows will not really feel at home on the iPad. Best of luck to you, though.